# How install memcached in Mac Bigsur with PHP 7.3 and home brew

Tags: apache, memcached, macos-big-sur, php-7.3

I am working on a project with setup `PHP7.3`, `Drupal 6.4` with `memcached`. Memcached is working in server and in my local machine with windows. But I am not able to make it work in my `Mac` machine. I followed the below link to make this work.

https://www.journaldev.com/1/install-memcached-mac

And I tried

```
brew install memcached
```

Also.

Then added

```
[memcached]
 extension="memcached.so"
```

In `php.ini` file. Then restarted apache. After this on the first run I got the error

> {"Error Details":{"Message":"\n Error code : 32\n  Message : PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcached.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/memcached.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/memcached.so, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/memcached.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/memcached.so.so, 9): image not found))\n File name : Unknown\n  Line no : 0\n   Date :12-March-21 02:45:05\n  Path : http://localhost/mysite/?q="}}

But from the second run onwards the error is not there. But memcache is not working. And I can't find the memcached.so file in my system.

How can I fix this? Please help

Answer (score 6):

I tried this. It helps.

https://izziswift.com/how-to-install-memcached-module-for-php7-1-on-macos-high-sierra/

1. `pecl bundle memcached`
2. Change to the directory it output.
3. `phpize`
4. Make sure libmemcached and zlib are installed (`brew install libmemcached zlib`).
5. Get the zlib directory (`brew list zlib`).
6. `./configure --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/` (replace the zlib path with the one from the previous command).
7. `make`
8. `make install`
9. Add the extension line in your php.ini file (ex. change the paths to match what make install output. I added this to my `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d` directory in a file called `ext-memcached.ini`.

```
[memcached] 
extension=memcached.so
```

10. Verify you installed the module `php -m` should show you memcached in the outputted list.

Comment: Working great on Monterey! Thanks :)

Comment: I am new to php and I'm trying to setup my mac ventura with these instructions. Getting an error: zsh: no such file or directory: ./configure when trying to execute line 6 in this instructions. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to start the service?

`brew services start memcached`

Comment: I have tried this. The service is up and running and I can see that when I check the status. Tried restart the system. No success.